# Automate testing of Silverlight application : MS Test Manager vs Selenium

Tags: silverlight, selenium, automated-tests, silverlight-5.0, microsoft-test-manager

We are trying to start implementing automated tests for our **Silverlight 5** application on VS2013.

Our first idea was to use **Microsoft Test Manager**, but when we looked into the Coded UI plugin for Silverlight, the reviews were pretty bad (2 stars out of 5). 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51b4a94a-1878-4dcc-81e0-7dc92131d2da

We also heard that testing Silverlight applications was possible using **Selenium**.

Do you have any experience with **one or the other**? How did it go? If you tried both, **which one** do you think was working better?

Comment: Selenium does **not** support Silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need the Test Studio, hence the [Telerik Testing Framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework) is **free**. I did used it for Silverlight and with a few tutorials you'll be up to speed in no time.

Most valuable key features are - *Rich-API* (Testing Framework exposes numerous properties and methods to help you easily build non-brittle, maintainable functional tests) and *Set implicit and explicit waits*. Also *Cross-Browser Compatibility* is well supported.

Another very used tool is [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). It automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code. So..flash, desktop etc. The [JAVA API](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to consider a different tool? [Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio) can test Silverlight applications.

Disclaimer: I work for Telerik.